# Tags flash, adobe-flash and flash-player

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

[flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash):

> Adobe Flash is a cross-platform multimedia runtime used to embed animations, video, and interactive applications into web pages. According to Adobe, Flash delivers over 75% of online video and the majority of casual gaming. It is installed on an estimated 96% to 99% of internet-connected desktop computers, and the newest version (10.1) was recently released for Android 2.2 mobile devices.

[adobe-flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash):

> For questions about the Adobe Creative Suite Flash product, the software used to create Flash videos and animations. For questions about the Adobe Flash Player, use [flash-player] instead.

[flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player):

> Adobe Flash Player is a plug-in for web browsers that enables viewing multimedia and interactive content created on the Adobe Flash (formerly Macromedia Flash) platform. It is one of the most popular and ubiquitous pieces of software, estimated to be installed on over 90% of personal computers.

While **flash** superficially looks to be similar to **adobe-flash**, it's clearly a synonym for **flash-player**. How about keeping **adobe-flash** and **flash-player**, and replacing all instances of **flash** with the latter? (Except of course for those rare instances where someone used it mistakenly to refer to the former, which is what should be used to replace it then.)

Comment: Sounds good. So, this means going through `flash` and retagging anything that's supposed to be `adobe-flash` (and not `flash-player`). We can keep `flash` on the questions about `flash-player` and then just merge them. I'm fairly certain Adobe Flash questions are much less common than those about the Flash player.

Comment: @slhck I think we should also rename `[adobe-flash]` since it sounds too similar to `[flash-player]` - how about `[adobe-flash-player]` & `[adobe-flash-suite]` or `[flash-player]` & `[flash-suite]`?

Comment: @tempy: Wikipedia calls them [Adobe Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_flash) and [Adobe Flash Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player) I think we should follow suit.

Comment: Merging all variants to [Adobe Flash Player] sounds good for me too.

Answer (score 2):

On Wikipedia, the authoring tool is called [Adobe Flash Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Professional).

I propose we do the following. [flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash) should be disambiguated to either [adobe-flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) or [flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player) and then be synonymized with [flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player).

To make it clearer to users that one is the authoring application, the other the player, [adobe-flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) should be renamed to [adobe-flash-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-professional) or [flash-professional](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-professional).

Comment: Why not adobe-flash-player?

Comment: @Braiam: Because we generally don't put the manufacturer's name in front of every product tag unless it adds something (at least, as far as I'm concerned). We don't need to quality the "windows" tag by adding "microsoft" to it. With "flash" it is important to show that we're referring to the software product, not the kind of memory, so the company name helps here (especially since people don't seem to be very aware that the "professional" suffix designates the authoring application). However, people are generally already aware that the "flash player" is manufactured by a company called "adobe"

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - We do however put Microsoft in front of a lot of tags like the Office Suite programs, and if I'm not mistaken a few other company-products get the same treatment (Norton springs to mind). I'd say [windows] is the exception, because it's ubiquitous for Microsoft's OS for the time being.

Comment: @Robotnik Right, in cases where it isn't obvious what product is being referred to ("office" being a prime example), adding the company name makes sense. Honestly though, I really have nothing against `adobe-flash-player`, I just didn't think it was necessary to be that verbose. I wouldn't aggressively oppose it though.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - fair enough. Its not something I lose sleep over so whatever is decided I'll support wholeheartedly, but I'd prefer to be consistent and unambiguous :-)

Answer (score 0):

I started writing a question to ask this very same thing, so instead I'm going to write my suggestions as an answer.

I think the adobe tags should have 'adobe' in front of them, to match how we handle other company products like the [Microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel+or+microsoft-word+or+microsoft-outlook+or+microsoft-excel-2010+or+microsoft-office+or+microsoft-excel-2007+or+microsoft-outlook-2010+or+microsoft-outlook-2007+or+microsoft-word-2010+or+microsoft-powerpoint+or+microsoft-word-2007+or+microsoft+or+microsoft-access+or+microsoft-excel-2013+or+microsoft-virtual-pc+or+microsoft-office-2007+or+microsoft-office-2010+or+microsoft-outlook-2013+or+microsoft-excel-2003+or+microsoft-visio) line. So, without further ado:

#### Rename

- [photoshop-cs3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-cs3) -> [adobe-photoshop-cs3](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs3)
- [photoshop-cs4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-cs4) -> [adobe-photoshop-cs4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs4)
- [photoshop-cs5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-cs5) -> [adobe-photoshop-cs5](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs5)
- [photoshop-cs6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-cs6) -> [adobe-photoshop-cs6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-cs6)
- [photoshop-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-7) -> [adobe-photoshop-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-7)
- [flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player) -> [adobe-flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-player)
- [photoshop-elements](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-elements) -> [adobe-photoshop-elements](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-elements)
- [flash-cs6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-cs6)* -> [adobe-flash-cs6](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-cs6)

<sub>*I'm not entirely sure which this tag is referencing, it's possible it should be merged with another tag?</sub>

---

As mentioned in the tag excerpt and comments above, [adobe-flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) is meant to be for *Adobe Creative Suite Flash*, but is being used for other flash related products.

I therefore propose that this tag be renamed also:

- [adobe-flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) -> [adobe-flash-suite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-suite)

#### Burn/Replace

- [adobe](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe) - [Manufacturer & Company Tags](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/107240) should be replaced with specific product tags, adobe is also listed there.
- [flash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash) - This is used for any and all things to do with flash technology, we should try and replace the use of this tag with other, more specific tags, and eventually make it a synonym of [adobe-flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-player)

#### Good tags

And for completeness sake, here are the other adobe tags I came across (that I think are fine):

[adobe-creative-suite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-creative-suite)
[adobe-acrobat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-acrobat)
[adobe-reader](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-reader)
[adobe-illustrator](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator)
[adobe-indesign](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign)
[adobe-premiere](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-premiere)
[adobe-fireworks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-fireworks)
[adobe-air](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-air)
[adobe-lightroom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-lightroom)
[adobe-after-effects](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-after-effects)
[adobe-media-encoder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-media-encoder)
[adobe-bridge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-bridge)

If there's anything I've missed or any other discrepancies you can spot let me know and I'll edit this

Comment: Strongly disagree with merging specific products (Photoshop) into the suite (Creative Suite). If you have an issue with Photoshop CS2, it should be tagged with that, not with the whole tag for CS2.

Comment: @slhck - OK that makes sense, I've removed that suggestion- the Photoshop tags can stay. Do you agree they should be appended with 'adobe' to be brought in line with the other tags? Or is there anything else in here that you don't agree with?

Comment: I disagree with the merge of [photoshop-cc] into [adobe-creative-cloud] for the same reason that slhck pointed out above.

Comment: @Cfinley - dunno how I missed your comment. I've just revisited this and overhauled all the suggestions here, including what you brought up :)

Comment: @Robotnik Everything looks good to me. Thanks for the update.